# This code gives error 9 subscript overflow in excel 2016. I don't understand why

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim LastRow as long

'Active sheet is sheet1
LastRow1 = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We need more details, in order to be able to help you. Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to find more information about how to ask a question.

Comment: I've never seen error 9 pertaining to `subscript overflow` maybe you mean either...`Error 6 Subscript Overflow` `Subscript out of range`. Please provide more information as this is not enough

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you have an error in your variable name.

Try this

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

In your post you Dim LastRow but tries to use LastRow1

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules, it would have detected the difference in variable names (it will save you a lot fo time in the future).

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetLastRow()

Dim LastRow As Long

'Active sheet is sheet1
With Sheets("sheet1")
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

End Sub
```